# LESS Variable in Javascript Giving Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, math, less

I've created a Javascript expression to evaluate the widths of columns based on some desired folding characteristics I want my grid system to have, but my [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) code gives me a "syntax error".  Here is my code:

```
.setColumnWidths(@maxcolumns, @num_cols, @min_resolution){
    @media screen and(min-width: @min_resolution) {
        .row {
            .onecol {
                width: ~ `Math.min(100%, (100% / {@num_cols}*Math.ceiling({@num_cols}*1/{@maxcolumns})))`;
            }
            .twocol {
            ~ `  Math.min(100%, (100% / {@num_cols}*Math.ceiling({@num_cols}*2/{@maxcolumns})))  `;
            }
            .threecol {
                width: ~ `Math.min(100%, (100% / {@num_cols}*Math.ceiling({@num_cols}*3/{@maxcolumns})))`;
            }
            .fourcol {
                width: ~ `Math.min(100%, (100% / {@num_cols}*Math.ceiling({@num_cols}*3/{@maxcolumns})))`;
            }
            .fivecol {
                width: ~ `Math.min(100%, (100% / {@num_cols}*Math.ceiling({@num_cols}*5/{@maxcolumns})))`;
            }
            .sixcol {
                width: ~ `Math.min(100%, (100% / {@num_cols}*Math.ceiling({@num_cols}*6/{@maxcolumns})))`;
            }
            .sevencol {
                width: ~ `Math.min(100%, (100% / {@num_cols}*Math.ceiling({@num_cols}*7/{@maxcolumns})))`;
            }
            .eightcol {
                width: ~ `Math.min(100%, (100% / {@num_cols}*Math.ceiling({@num_cols}*8/{@maxcolumns})))`;
            }
            .ninecol {
                width: ~ `Math.min(100%, (100% / {@num_cols}*Math.ceiling({@num_cols}*9/{@maxcolumns})))`;
            }
            .tencol {
                width: ~ `Math.min(100%, (100% / {@num_cols}*Math.ceiling({@num_cols}*10/{@maxcolumns})))`;
            }
            .elevencol {
                width: ~ `Math.min(100%, (100% / {@num_cols}*Math.ceiling({@num_cols}*11/{@maxcolumns})))`;
            }
            .twelvecol {
                width: ~ `Math.min(100%, (100% / {@num_cols}*Math.ceiling({@num_cols}*12/{@maxcolumns})))`;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will allow "folding", upon calling the mixin:

```
.setColumnWidths(12, 4, 420px);
```

Here, we are declaring that the number of columns should be 4, the maximum number of columns is 12, and that this should occur when the screen width is 420px.

Why is this failing, and how can I evaluate these values using javascript otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a syntax error.  The proper syntax for referencing a variable in a JavaScript expression is `@{var_name}`.  You have `{@var_name}` in the code you posted.

Comment: Tried this, but I'm now getting the following error: `JavaScript evaluation error: `Math.min(100, ((100 / 4*Math.ceiling(4*1/@{maxcolumns)})))``  So I took out the percentages to make sure it would work... but still no luck.  Syntax is like so: `.onecol {
    width: ~`Math.min(100, (100 / @{num_cols}*Math.ceiling(@{num_cols}*1/@{maxcolumns})))`;
   }`

Comment: @user1429980 Try `Math.ceil()` instead of `Math.ceiling()`.